Можно ли так обойти ограничение?
Если кто-то лайкнул/дизлайкнул вопрос (или ответ), то если через некоторое время он попытается изменить свой голос, появится надпись:

Последний раз вы голосовали за этот вопрос <время> назад. Сейчас ваш голос блокирован до тех пор, пока вопрос не будет отредактирован.

Но если он так же проголосует за несколько вопросов от того же автора, то система заметит накрутку и откатит голоса, в том числе и тот.
Еще можно отредактировать вопрос, как указано здесь.

Не понятно о каком ограничении идет речь, и как "так" его обойти.

Ограничение, которое не дает переголосовать

Скажем так, массовое голосование - это "на грани фола". Вряд ли стоит этим пользоваться для отката своих голосов. Нормальный вариант переголосовать - отредактировать сообщение, потом снять голос.

А зачем менять голос через время?

Сомнительный способ. Насколько я представляю, автоматический откат произойдёт только в рамках одного дня. А если ручное, то там все голоса по отношению к пользователю отменят, а тебя отправят в бан.
